# Setting a path for the main-class in the manifest file

Tags: java, jar, manifest, program-entry-point, entry-point

Say for example my manifest.txt file is saved in a parent directory of my bin directory where by classes are saved. Now, I want to be able to refer to my main-class in the manifest header so that I may create my JAR file from the parent directory directly.
So for example:
my manifest.txt is saved in the directory called project so:

-project(parent directory) contains: 
    bin(this contains my classes that are needed to run the application)
    ,src(folder)
     and manifest.txt

So in a perfect world I would imagine my manifest.txt to look something like this:
Main-Class: bin/*mainclass*

but for some reason this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Main-Class attribute must contain the fully qualified name of the main class. That has nothing to do with how your project is laid out. If the class is named `Foo` and is in package `com.bar`, the main class is `com.bar.Foo`.

If the class Foo is in the default package, which is a bad practice, then its fully qualified name is `Foo`. But the first thing you should do in that case is moving the class to a package.

When you execute `java -jar path/to/myjar.jar`, from whatever directory, java will inspect the jar, read the manifest file, look for the Main-Class, and load it from the jar.

Comment: Say I want to keep it in the default package and I want to access it(i.e. set it as my main class in the manifest) from the parent directory. Is there no way to set a path that leads to it? So that the manifest may theoretically look something like this: Main-Class: bin/foo

Comment: Why do you care about directories? The class is inside the jar, and you tell java, thanks to the manifest, which of the classes inside the ar is the main one. Whether you do things from bin, c:\, or even another machine running another OS doesn't matter: a jar file is a jar file.